# Storing number of lines to a variable in UNIX bin/sh

Tags: shell

I have a portion in my script which gets the number of files based on the filelist.txt. I'm using this command to store the number to a variable.

`filecount=$(wc -l ${script_path}/$filelist.txt | cut -d " " -f 1)`

It works ok in my CentOS VM Image, but when it is executed in a UNIX environment it shows this error:

```
/myscript.sh: syntax error at line 50: `filecount=$' unexpected
./myscript.sh: [[: not found
```

The filelist contains this which actually just contains a listing of expected files to be processed.

```
File1
File2
File3
```

Appreciate any thoughts on this? Does cut not applicable to unix? What alternative methods can I use to get the desired result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test on an UNIX `sh` but I think you just have to replace `$()` with ``` `` ```

```
filecount=`wc -l ${script_path}/$filelist.txt | cut -d " " -f 1`
```

Regards